# AngularJS | ngAnimate Form Errors

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ng-animate

I have my form errors displaying fine at the moment using css / conditional classes however, I've discovered `ng-message` and `ng-animate`.

Can `ng-message` be used to house the error messages? I also can't find any tutorials on animating ( fading in the error messages ) using `ng-animate`.

Currently I'm using `ng-show`:

```
<div class="form-input-error" ng-show="loginForm.username.$error.maxlength">
 Username is too long.
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle example to see in action: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/beuL679o/14/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add css rules tied to `form-input-error` in order to perform the animation on ng-show. When ng-animate is included it adds some css classes to the element inorder for us to define rules. Some of the classes added are ng-hide-add, ng-hide-add-active,ng-hide-remove, ng-hide-remove-active and ng-hide. Take a look at the examples provided in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#example).

So you could define rules for:

```
.form-input-error {
  /*elements default properties when it is displayed*/
}
.form-input-error.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.form-input-error.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  /*Set animation rules*/
}
.form-input-error.ng-hide {
  /*elements  properties that changes when it hides*/
}
```

**Demo**

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

});
```

```css
.form-input-error {
  line-height: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
}
.form-input-error.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active,
.form-input-error.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}
.form-input-error.ng-hide {
  line-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="loginForm">
    <input required name="username" ng-model="username">
    <div class="form-input-error" ng-show="loginForm.username.$error.required">
      Username is required.
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

You could also use [ng-messages/ng-message](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/docs/api/ngMessages#animations), in order to use it you would need to include `angular-ngmessages` script and list `ngMessages` module as dependency. You can have 2 levels of animations with ng-messages,

- ng-active/ng-inactive animation for the container (`ngMessages`)
- enter/leave animation classes for the inner message sections (`ngMessage`)

A sample demo:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngMessages']).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

});
```

```css
.form-input-error {
  line-height: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  color: red;
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}
.form-input-error.ng-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.form-input-error.ng-inactive {
  opacity: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.form-input-error > .message {
  background: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
.form-input-error > .message.ng-enter,
.form-input-error > .message.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
}
.form-input-error > .message.ng-enter,
.form-input-error > .message.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
.form-input-error > .message.ng-leave,
.form-input-error > .message.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="loginForm">
    <input required name="username" ng-model="username" minlength=5>

    <div ng-messages="loginForm.username.$error" class="form-input-error">
      <div ng-message="required" class="message">Username is required.</div>
      <div ng-message="minlength" class="message">minlength is 5.</div>
    </div>

  </form>



</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not seeing the ng-message or ng-animate tags being used? What I'm wanting to do is to replace my current div that has "form-input--error" with ng-message. Is this possible?

Comment: @Filth See my update with some animations, but you will get the basic idea looking at classes

Comment: Thanks for this - are you able to add this code to my Fiddle? I'm having a hard time understanding how to append ngAnimate and ngMessages to my existing module and get this to run. See fiddle link in question.

Comment: I can only access fiddle after I get home.. :(

Comment: No worries, I am appending as we speak - I will post the link for you to check.

Comment: Yes it is! Thanks for the plnkr demo @PSL!